# Get all dates from a string in C#

Tags: c#, split

I am using a web based DOTNET application in which I have a log column in database, Whenever user adds a comments in comments textarea on UI,  the date, his name along with the comment are appended to the exisiting data in database. Below is the format in which the column has data:

```
04/05/11 17:10:19 (user2):Work Log -
Closing.
03/31/11 09:40:02 (user2):Work Log -
Support provided over phone.
03/31/11 09:39:43 (user1):Work Log –
Awaiting support reply
03/30/11 11:30:08 (user2):Work Log -
Manager notified by standard e-mail communication.
03/30/11 11:29:30 (user1):Work Log -
Emailed support team
03/30/11 11:28:52 (user1):Work Log -
I have an issue with my Xbox.
```

I am trying to now pull all the dates (just the dates) when these comments are entered. I tried  many options but none helped.

Comment: Isn't this begging for `fldDateTime|fldUser|fldMessage`

Comment: are you retrieving it as single huge string or is it single string per comment? What exactly did you try? How about taking a substring of first 17 characters every other line?

Comment: @StaWho I am fetching full string in one go, I can't go by alternate lines as there are chances that the comment can be multiline.

Comment: @TRR. If you are extracting that whole bunch of text into a single string variable then regex really is your only option, as per my answer, but it does seem like a database redesign with a single log per row, and a date, user and comment column would make your life a lot easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want to do this in C# code:

```
Regex splitter = new Regex("[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}");
foreach (Match m in splitter.Matches(theDatabaseValue)) {
    string dateString = m.Groups[0].Value;
    DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, "MM/dd/yy HH:mm:ss", null);
}
```

The nice thing about the regex approach is that you can extend it to also extract the user:

```
Regex splitter = new Regex("(?<date>[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}) \\((?<user>.+)\\)");
foreach (Match m in splitter.Matches(theDatabaseValue)) {
    string dateString = m.Groups["date"].Value;
    DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, "MM/dd/yy HH:mm:ss", null);
    string user = m.Groups["user"].Value;
    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", dt.ToString(), user);
}
```

and therefore even the message (I haven't done that part of the regex as I'm not sure if you have line breaks before the message or not, it seems like you do).

Once you've done this you could create a database table that has three columns, date, user, comment, and then transform the existing table to that one using the regex and make your life in the future a lot easier!

Comment: corrected date format in code: it is Month/Day/Year as per the OP sample

Comment: Works like charm... using regex is only option left now for me. Thanks a lot Andy

Answer (score 0):

You should refactor your database to store the data in three columns (DateTime, User, Comment) this will greatly improve performance and usability.

But if this is not an option you can use [DateTime.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch92fbc1.aspx) to get the value from the string.  Eg:

```
        string comment = "04/05/11 17:10:19 (user2):Work Log - Closing.";

        string dateSection = comment.Substring(0, 17);

        DateTime date;

        if (!DateTime.TryParse(dateSection, out date))
        {
            throw new Exception(string.Format("unable to parse string '{0}'", dateSection));
        }
```